# Class not found exception on android

Tags: android, adt

I get some soure from net. and import on my workspace.  When i run on emulator, its throws,

```
 "05-28 17:30:47.895: E/AndroidRuntime(840): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{com.developmentmill.laserlogic/com.developmentmill.laserlogic.StageActivity}:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.developmentmill.laserlogic.StageActivity in
 loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.developmentmill.laserlogic-2.apk]"
```

But when i run the same code on my friend machine, its running without any error.

My eclipse ADT Version is 17.0 my friend eclipse ADT version is 16.0

I copy the jar files from lib folder to libs foder. and change the java build path from lib to libs folder. and also i cleaned the project.

Again, i run the project, the same error has been throw.

What is the problem and how to correct it? y its occur on my machine only. Pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced this problem.

so try this.

`Right click on project -> goto properties -> Java buid path -> libraries -> remove all External Jars from here -> press OK`

also remove all jars from **libs** folder

**clean project -> restart eclipse.**

Then again put all required jars in **libs** folder.

I have solved my problem by this

hope this will help you....

Answer (score 0):

First create **libs** folder in your project and then add all jar file or library file used in project  in libs folder and now run your project.

It will definitely run.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:
I already had a libs folder in the same hierarchy as my src & res folders. 
The FlurryAgent.jar file was saved on my Desktop. I simply right clicked on the FlurryAgent file, copied it. Then I pasted the file into the libs folder in Eclipse. 
Eclipse automatically copied the FlurryAgent.jar file into the “Android Dependencies” folder also.