# Error in Flurry Analytic integration in android

Tags: android, flurry

I am trying to integrate Flurry analytic in android app.

I have integrate successfully but it gives runtime error of "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent"` in my onStart method.

Any suggestion??

Comment: where you placed the jar file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

or http://stackoverflow.com/a/10784598/1289716

Comment: @padma Kumar : i have placed jar file in lib folder and set jar as class path.

Comment: thats the problem change lib to libs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Android project, create a directory named libs at the root of your project (next to src/, res/, etc.)

Locate the JAR file for the library you want to use and copy it into the libs/ directory.

[Setting Up a Project to Use a Library:](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#SettingUp)

[More refer here:](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html)

Comment: You can also add it as an external JAR. But make sure it is also checked under Java Build Path -> Order and Export Tab.

Answer (score -1):

I had that same error…

What worked for me was:
I already had a libs folder in the same hierarchy as my src & res folders. 
The FlurryAgent.jar file was saved on my Desktop. I simply right clicked on the FlurryAgent file, copied it. Then I pasted the file into the libs folder in Eclipse. 
Eclipse automatically copied the FlurryAgent.jar file into the “Android Dependencies” folder also.

Comment: Whilst this is your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784443/class-not-found-exception-on-android/15520060#15520060 you shouldn't be re-posting it. You should be advising the user in comments by providing the link.