# Using Android Library Project

Tags: android, admob

I am developing an android project. In my project I referenced an android library project. The library project has a referenced  "google admobe libary". When I invoke the admob class from my application, it closes with "No classdef error". Please help me...

Comment: How have you added the library to your project?

Comment: On my Libary project Properties -> Java Build path ->Libaries ->Add external Jars->Added admob libary. On my main application i refrenced the libary project by properties ->Andriod ->add -> added the libary project

Comment: Need to move your jar to libs folder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10848701/1012284

Comment: I moved the jar to libs folder..but the error occur still

Answer (score 0):

If admob has any jar file dependencies, you will need to copy those into your main project and make sure they are added appropriately in your project settings.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals

Comment: I used the admob in another application..it works..But when i refrenced the admob in my libary project and i referenced the libary project in my application,i cant invoke it..The output of libary project is only 2kb.The jar file doen't include the admob jar

Comment: Yes but an external jar that is referenced in your library project will not automatically be copied across to your main project. You have to manually copy it into your libs folder of your main project and add the jar in properties menu as before.