# Android Flurry Events

Tags: android, flurry

I have gone through the [tutorial](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android) and did exactly what it said. I gave **INTERNET,COARSE_LOCATION,FINE_LOCATION** permissions. Added jar file in the libraries. It's not working. App is getting crashed at **FlurryAgent.onStartSession()**. This is the code that I am using as given by them:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(MainActivity.this, MY_KEY);//MY_KEY is key given by them.
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:31)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1166)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3842)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1719)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1765)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:158)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:996)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3850)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
08-28 16:52:49.499: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in Flurry Analytic integration in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848432/error-in-flurry-analytic-integration-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It obviously crashes at runtime, you may check that your jar is exported when building apk: in project Properties > Java Build Path, go to the 'Order and Export' folder and fill the checkbox corresponding to your jar. And rebuild.

Comment: After doing above step it's giving **Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1**

Answer (score 3):

Well it obviously cannot find the `com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent` class. Check if the JAR contains such class. If not, it's the wrong JAR. If it does, you didn't include the JAR in your build path correctly.

Keep in mind that to do automatic adding to the build path you have to add it in the **`libs/`** directory (and not `lib/`). IIRC this has changed recently with the Android SDK update. Anyway I suggest you adding it manually to the build path to make sure.

Don't forget to clean and rebuild when done.