# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android sdk and ADT 20 Windows 64

Tags: android, jar, adt

Good morning ppl. I have what it looks like to be a commong problem in android, import jars from libraries. I'm trying to use a library to consume an in house api. I copied the jar into the libs folder on my android project and went to 
`Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries` and added the jar. Also, I checked the boxes within the jar name in the `Order and Export` tab. all I have is the

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception`.

I have read almost every post that points to the same answer. Put the jar on libs folder and make the steps listed above. Nothing worked. I'm running the ADT v 20, on the Indigo release on a Win 7 x64. I'm not very skilled on java or java architectures but this is driving me nuts. Anyone has a differente approach to this? I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do u have libs folder in your project? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10848701/1012284

Comment: Yes I had, the problem wasn't that I had to just dragging the jar into the libs dir, it was a problem building the jar, the lib was compiled with the open jdk and I was trying to build de jar with the oracle sdk. It worked and I marked as a good answer because I tryied with a jar built with the open jdk. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply drag the jar file into the libs folder and not manually add it. Try deleting the jar file from

> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

clean and rebuild the project.

Explanation:
The process of loading library has been automated and changed from ADT 16 onwards and it is not backward compatible with the older method. You were actually trying to use both the methods of adding library which was adding the library twice and breaking it.

Comment: Ok, this is awkward... how this works? and importing the jar o copying didnt worked? Thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

Go on the tab "Order and Export", inside "Properties->Java Build Path" and check the unchecked boxes. It worked here...