# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView

Tags: android, millennial-media

I am Using Millenial media in my app. i have several apps running with following code but now when i try to copy paste running code for new apps it shows the error  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView`

this is how i am creating `MMAdView` object and inserting it in my `Linear Layout`.

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutadd);
adview = new MMAdView(MyClass.this, MYAPID,"MMBannerAdBottom", 30);
myLayout.addView(adview, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
MMAdListener listener = new MyAdListener();
adview.setListener(listener);
adview.callForAd();
```

this is the xml declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdViewOverlayActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" >
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

i have also imported liabrary...

THIS THING IS WORKING IN MY OTHER APPS JUST IS THAT FROM FEW DAYS ITS NOT WORKING PROPERLY FOR NEW APPS.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716
 that may help you

Comment: then try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10784598/1289716

Comment: Have you updated the plugin and/or tools recently? In which folder is your .jar kept?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard or a similar thing?

Comment: tanx gtumca-MAC now its working
@RaghavSood libs

Comment: Whats the reason its happening? if anybody know pls let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the JAR file isn't copied onto the device. On [Millennial Media's wiki page](http://wiki.millennialmedia.com/index.php/Android#Add_the_Millennial_Media_Library), they show you how to add the JAR to your project. After you select the library (9th bullet point), but before you hit "OK", go to the "Order and Export" tab and make sure the checkbox next to MMAdView.jar is checked. By default, it isn't. Push OK and try running your program.

Comment: Link is not working. If possible please provide details here.